# when I delete a child object, will my parent object also be deleted in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I am working with Hibernate, when I delete my child object my parent object also deleted please check my code below.

```
@Entity
public class User
{
     @Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "FLD_USER_ID")
private Long userId;
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private java.util.List<UserProfileEx> userProfileEx = new ArrayList<UserProfileEx();

}
 @Entity
  @Table(name="TBL_STD_USERPROFILEEX")
    public class UserProfileEx implements Serializable {
     @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name="FLD_FIELD_ID")
 private Long userProfileExId;
    @ManyToOne
private UserProfile userProfile;
 }
```

MyDelete code

```
    @Override
   public void delete(T classObj, Integer id) {
      T entity = get(classObj, id);
      if (entity != null)
      getHibernateTemplate().delete(entity);
     }
```

MyLogic

```
 I have UserProfileEx object here with id=1
 Now I am calling my delete method like this
  delete(UserProfileExObj,1);
```

it's deleted from childtable at the same time deleted parent table object also any one help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cascade attribute is set to `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` meaing that the operation (save, delete, update, evict, lock, replicate, merge, persist) will cascate to mapping.

`CascadeType=ALL` means that, if you do a operation, they are all operations (save, delete, update, evict, lock, replicate, merge, persist) here, it will be cascaded to all relations. If you delete an object other objects will also be deleted.

If you do not need any cascade operation then set id None `cascade=CascadeType.NONE`, so other object will not be effected.

You should pick a proper cascade type which is needed.

Please see the doc for more cascade types.

**See also**

[Enum CascadeType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the replay.but i added cascade=CascadeType.ALL in my parent table..can you tell me how it is working

Comment: See my edit. i suggest to you set `cascade=CascadeType.NONE` for now. However, you should select a proper cascade attribute as you need.